# Chatty comment flags are chatty

Tags: discussion, comment-flags

Since [chatty comment threads already get directed to chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/74243/1228) why bother keeping the "too chatty" comment flag?

I don't ever recall its use being beneficial.  I also don't like the fact that *you can't actually determine if a comment is too chatty without visiting the post in question*.  The flag queue doesn't hold enough context to be able to determine if it really reaches the level that it **needs moderator attention**.

Do we need to bug moderators because someone added a "Thanks!  This worked for me!" comment to an answer?  I'd hate to think we were expected to eradicate all encouragement or kind words from a post.  Kinda not good for the community.

The "more than 20 comments" flag is more effective in indicating something *actually* needs to be peeped.

Why bother?  Down with the "too chatty" flag!

Comment: Me, too! <15 chars>

Comment: Feels like grabbing them in both hands

Comment: This is kind of priceless, all things considered.

Comment: Awesome, would read again.

Comment: All these happy comments and no upvotes? Sounds typical.

Comment: If somebody doesn't flag this comment as "too chatty" I'm going to poop myself.

Comment: If my flag gets declined, I'm going to poop myself

Comment: That's where I saw the Leprechaun. He tells me to burn things!

Comment: @Pekka - which leprechaun?  [This one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DM7CL-Vyo1U&feature=youtube_gdata_player)??

Comment: @Adam "... a crackhead on the wrong stuff..." hilarious!

Comment: @Pekka that's it? That's your new screen name? I'm *dissapointed*.

Comment: @casperOne wait 30 days! The text is already finished. Still looking for a good picture.

Answer (score 14):

I appreciate your concern, but I don't agree with your proposed solution.

Having “chatty” comments hurts because they impede the visibility of future, more useful comment. As a moderator on a smaller site, where I see one comment flag per day and not one per minute, here are some of [my guidelines](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1617/what-should-we-do-about-comments/1618#1618) that apply here:

- If it's likely to **generate a lot of replies**, only keep if it's firmly on-topic.
- If it's a standalone joke or other by-the-way item, remove only when the number of comments approaches **the limit after which not all comments are shown**, to leave room for possible future more useful comments to be visible. It's more important to leave room on questions than on answers.

There was a time when the community (10kers) could pile onto comment flags and so moderators rarely had to intervene on them. Was this a problem? Could we not deliver moderators from having to deal with comment flags?

Comment: Man, that seems like a *lot* of work for little benefit.

Comment: @Won't Another of my guidelines is “If someone took the trouble to flag it, and it's not obviously relevant (e.g. pointing out a mistake in a post), delete.”

Comment: At the very least it might be that this flag has more value for small sites than it does for SO