# What is the best option to flag a comment like "+1" or "Works fine"?

Tags: support, comments, comment-flags

On Stack Overflow I see many comments like "+1", "great answer", and "yeah man!". What is the best way to flag them?

Comment: They really aren't constructive responses, almost verging on spam, couldn't they just be flagged as that if you get a lot of comments like it. (And it's taking all of my restraint not to sarcastically post +1)

Comment: @CBredlow: Don't flag them as spam, spam comments are handled differently and might throw of future hueristics to auto-detect spam.

Comment: More information on [the post that introduced the feature](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93821/what-are-valid-reasons-for-flagging-comments?rq=1)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125541/chatty-comment-flags-are-chatty

Answer (score 11):

These are best flagged as chatty.

Comment: I'd expect that "Not Constructive" would be good, too, because they're...not constructive.

Comment: @Valet Tree: That too, but I guess "chatty" gets the point across; "not constructive" on the other hand sounds rather abstract to me. Either one works, though.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Me too!

Comment: So when would you use "Not constructive" and  when "Too Chatty"?

Comment: @MrLister: Why do you need to know that? <-- Not constructive.