# Can we add more information to "no longer needed" flags?

Tags: feature-request, comment-flags

As a moderator on a couple comment-heavy sites, I see a lot of "no longer needed" comment flags.  But that doesn't tell me *why* it's no longer needed, so to evaluate it I usually have to read through a bunch of other comments or review edits to try to figure out what the flagger had in mind.  But the flagger already *knows* why it's obsolete -- if only he could tell me, without ignoring the built-in flag reason and resorting to an "other" flag.

Could we add one more mouse click to "no longer needed" flags?  Maybe something like this, after a user flags as obsolete:

[image: sample menu - post edited, reply to deleted comment, time-sensitive, other?]

The first two options cover the vast majority of such flags I see, though other sites might be different.  I don't know if the third happens enough to be worth the menu space.  I sometimes see such flags on comments that are just plain old -- "@user ^^^" to get someone's attention, comments like "I'll edit in sources tomorrow" (and it didn't happen), etc.  That's the sort I had in mind with this option.

I don't know if an "other" option should be offered.  And this menu doesn't allow for a "naked" flag (no further explanation); I don't know if that's good or bad.  So I'm not proposing *this exact implementation*, but am instead asking if some further explanation of obsolescence could be supported in the flag UI.

After posting this I was reminded that I'd previously asked [another question arising from the same problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261009/162102).  In that feature request I asked that flaggers be identified, and the response was that that wouldn't help all that much.  This is asking about allowing the flagger to directly communicate the reason rather than leaving it to mods to figure out.  Can we do *something* to add information to the obsolete flag?

Comment: **Yes, please!** I have had a bunch of "obsolete" comment flags declined because the mod clearly didn't know why I felt the comments were obsolete. I have had to then use the custom flags, which is a huge task.

Comment: I think you need to take the flag at face value, ***if*** such a choice should not be offered that's another matter entirely. If it's "No longer needed" then to decline the flag you would want to have a reason to keep it, and possibly write a comment praising it's greatness and preventing further flags. --- When *random person* (unassociated, and no horse in the race) makes a comment demanding further clairification from the asker or answerer it is their right to decline, comments disparaging the post but offering no improvement are also unwanted. Thus, no longer needed. It's polite.