# A flag was declined

Tags: discussion, comments, declined-flags

A couple of hours ago, [a comment I flagged](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18989877/1275169) as "too chatty" was *declined*. The whole post is deleted and only 10K+ users can see it now. So here's the screen shot of the post and the comment I flagged.

[image: gg]

While declining a flag is not a life-threatening issue for me, I started to wonder if it was declined only because it was a moderator's comment. Because I can't see how it can be a "constructive" comment. I have no doubt that that comment would have been deleted if it was a *normal* user. Perhaps, the rules are different for moderators?

On a bigger note, this behaviour worries me that moderators can't be criticized (or trusted to take decisions objectively) and they may misuse their power when it concerns them.

Comment: Going from a single declined flag straight to moderator conspiracy? That's kind of a big leap, isn't it?

Comment: What time was the flag response?  Was it by chance the exact time of the post's deletion?  If so, the response may have been automatic.  The post only lived for a few minutes before deletion, and comment flags often aren't handled that quickly.

Comment: The decline is not an issue (That's my 83rd and I never had a problem with the previous 82 declinations). Rather I am concerned about the *behaviour*.

Comment: @KingsIndian The point is that you have used one example to claim a pattern of behavior.  If you plan to demonstrate a pattern of behavior in which mod content is never acted on by flags you'll need to supply quite a lot more proof that you currently have.

Comment: @KingsIndian I think flags on comments are auto-declined if the parent post is deleted.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I would have suspected them to be marked as disputed instead.

Comment: The decline wasn’t automatic.

Comment: @Servy Agreed. Single instance is not enough sample. But I expected that to be deleted definitely. And any comment would be deleted if it's not useful. What's your defence for that decline?

Comment: "What's your defence for that decline?" I think I'll go with the King's Indian.

Comment: @Yannis too bad there's no "King's Indian Declined"

Comment: I am not sure why I am getting downvoted. May be, I have upset the establishment? :)

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter alas, [doesn't appear be a declined](http://chess.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bkings-indian%5D+declined).  Defenses tend not to be 'declined' as they are responses... [its the gambits that are declined](http://chess.stackexchange.com/search?q=declined)... but now we're just mixing SE's around and that can get messy.

Comment: @MichaelT Decline is usually done when *gambits* are offered. So Kings Indian defense can't be declined :P

Comment: @minitech Would you mind telling who declined that comment?

Comment: What good would that do @KingsIndian. If they want to come here and say why then that's good but knowing a name doesn't help you, unless you want to start a conversation/argument elsewhere.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Because I strongly suspect only the concerned mod immediately declined it and *any other mod* wouldn't have declined it IMHO. The name is quite *relevant* here.

Comment: The name is relevant to other mods/SE; assuming it was Robert who declined your flag, which you've no proof of. _You_, personally, can do nothing apart from try to kick up a stink off this page; if it was Robert (once again no proof). I don't see the point. I guess that it's almost reached the stage where it would be better if the mod who did this was named just to stop the implied accusations. P.S. I agree with you; the flag should probably have not  been declined if that was all there was at the time you flagged but throwing around accusations isn't the right way to get anything sorted.

Comment: If you have reasons to believe a moderator is out to get you, then your best course of action would be to contact SE directly @KingsIndian.

Comment: @Yannis I have no reason to believe that Robert is targeting me and never had any issue with him or any other mod for that matter. It's just that I get the feeling that I had hurt his ego here (I-am-a-mod-and-you-can't-flag-my-funny-comments) which led me to question the flag decline.

Comment: No flag is a bigger waste of time than "chatty" flags.

Comment: @Won't What do you mean? We shouldn't flag anything as "chatty" then?

Comment: @KingsIndian Well, they are a bit... ehh... usually. If it's not bad enough to be 'Not Constructive', I'm not sure what the point is. I think every 'Chatty' flag I have deleted in response to could have been a Not Constructive.

Comment: @KingsIndian: Look at this entire thread.  Think about how much effort has been expended, how many calories have been burned over one insignificant comment.  Yes, I mean "chatty" flags are almost always completely a waste of everybody's time.  Comments are by definition "chatty."  SE's policy is that comments are not content and can be removed at any time.  Content should exist within questions and answers.  So every comment is chatty.  Why flag to have "thanks" or other such comments deleted?  The flag is worthless.

Comment: @Won't quite a pity that vast majority of flaggers are not aware of your opinion. A [meta-tag:feature-request]? "At comment flagging dialog, add a note for 'too chatty' option: _Warning! this may be declined because some believe that this flag is worthless_"

Comment: @gnat: [Already railed against them before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125541/chatty-comment-flags-are-chatty).  To delete/not delete a chatty flagged comment is still left up to the judgement of mods, so whether or not someone has that opinion doesn't really change anything.  The only comment flags I felt had any merit were Offensive, Obsolete, and Other.  The rest were normally a complete waste of time.

Comment: @Won't It's interesting you mentioned about the calories... Come to think of it, I do realize I spent a *lot* of my calories on SO about a lot of things that don't really affect me in anyway. I'll cut down the crappy things I do on SO. Thanks :)

Comment: @Won't again, quite a pity that majority of flaggers are not (and I guess will never be) aware of your MSO request. While we're at it, what flag would you recommend me when today some user posted a comment pinging me to revert a downvote they assumed was mine?

Comment: @gnat: Definitely offensive or other.  I'd probably do Other because it (IIRC) will stick to his account, so mods can see if accusing others of downvoting and demanding a reversal is a habit, which would be worthy of a mod message.  I might even flag a question/answer of his to make sure of it.

Comment: @Won't would it be safe to flag as _offensive_ comment that may be spelled as "dear gnat, would you please be so kind to revert a vote in case if it by chance happen to be yours"? I wonder whether moderator comparing the flag to comment text could quickly infer that it was meant to "offend". Your reasoning wrt Other flag makes good sense though - thanks

Answer (score 15):

It seems that comment has no quality and the flag should have been accepted. As it stands, by itself, edited or not, it is of no value. But I'm new here.

Answer (score 13):

You seem to have missed some context here. Prior to the comment from Robert you have quoted, he left this (which was deleted and is visible only to moderators now):

> He has seven significant figures.

and the OP left this in reply (also deleted and not visible):

> Not the second time round ;-)

Which generated a comment which content we don't know - because the "Meh" is actually the edited version of the comment. Your question here makes it sound/look like Robert simply replied "Meh" to the answer, which was not the case.

What was the content originally? And what was the state of the comment when you flagged and when it was declined? Those are kind of important.

Comment: Even if it was edited reply to someone else's comment, how can it justify that comment's declination? Why would anyone care about the context of *deleted* comments which only mods can see.

Comment: @KingsIndian The timeline of edits, deletes, flagging and handling of the flag are *absolutely critical* to this issue. Even insofar as it is an issue to begin with.

Comment: `Your question here makes it sound/look like Robert simply replied "Meh" to the answer, which was not the case.` I am repeating my previous comment here... Why the deleted/edited comment's context matter here? It's not like I flagged before the edits/replies. Everything that was there when I flagged is still there. The decline was done when everything was in its present form there now.

Comment: Imagine a trail of comments, A, B, and C. A and B are deleted and you can't see them, leaving C alone looking non constructive. You flag C as not constructive. A moderator looks, sees A and B, and interprets C as a response to them, and feels it's constructive enough. What it is now is actually obsolete (as well as a symptom of a poor answer) but moderators have a new MO where the reason has to be right- while it probably doesn't apply to flags, I bet the mindset does - so your flag is declined. And later the whole mess is deleted leaving us to pick over the bones for clues.

Comment: @KateGregory As I said in the previous comment, if something was obsolete it was obsolete even before my flag. So if the C was response to A & B, why would that matter? Isn't that exact purpose of "obsolete" option to remove them?

Comment: @KingsIndian: Read the rest of that comment, about the flag reason needing to be right.

Comment: @minitech I take your silence as "yes" and see no point in discussing anything further.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion this was a poor choice of flag:

- You flagged a *comment* on a low quality answer, when instead you could have flagged the low quality answer.

In fact, you the question itself deserved to be closed / deleted (and in fact it has now been deleted). Your flag/close/delete vote would have been better aimed directly at question - which is clearly the root of the problem, and this wouldn't require a moderator to intervene.

Comment: I flag a comment based on my judgement of its usefulness. Why would I care about the quality of the post it was commented on?

Comment: I do agree with @KingsIndian here; a comment flag should stand on its own and does not necessarily preclude or interfere with whether the parent post is also flagged.

Comment: @AndrewBarber interesting you say that, I've had flags declined before saying specifically that I should have flagged/closed/deleted the question.

Comment: True... if the comment is sort of related to the post. But for an extreme example, imagine an offensive comment. It should still be flagged itself

Comment: While I see the point that flags should stand on their own, my opinion is that mods have limited time and hundreds of flags to address.  If the OP here did not flag the answer and chose to the flag the comment instead, then it deserved to be declined.

Comment: @psubsee2003 `If the OP here did not flag the answer and chose to the flag the comment instead, then it deserved to be declined`. I disagree: [flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167624/can-we-have-an-unambiguous-official-ruling-on-what-the-not-an-answer-flag-is). An answer can't be flagged for its *poor content* (unless it's a spam or "not-an-answer"). That answer is wrong but that's not enough to reason to flag it. That's what we have downvotes for.

Comment: @KingsIndian you can flag an answer as very low quality... But the more important thing imo is the question (it was always going to be closed/deleted).

Comment: @hayd I don't flag posts for technical inaccuracies. That's my judgement and also said on Meta (link above). How can it justify that my flag *deserved* to be declined because I didn't flag the answer?

Comment: @KingsIndian I don't think I said *"deserved"*, just that you'd have been better off flagging the answer or the question. (Is that answer ["beyond saving"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93606/184179), I would say yes.)

Comment: @hayd You didn't say but psubsee2003 said that. Whether it's a "beyond saving" or not is my judgement. That has no relation to the my flagging of the comment.